# Combine content from multiple pages into one page using itext 7

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I have a pdf insurance document and right now each clause is on a separate page. i want to get the pages that have a short clause and combine them with others into one page.

Here I am passing file which represents 2 pages. I am trying to understand the mechanics of how to do this with some test code.

I want to read in these two pages into a new target page and return that.

I dont want to change the scale of the original content but if I don't use the ConcatMatrix with the transform then it nothing gets displayed at all.

Here I can see the content of both pages in one page but they are too small. I am just playing around with the parameters into AddXObject. The parameters take a,b,c,d, etc, so how do you know which ones are for x,y,height,width.. ?

```
public byte[] ManipulatePdf(byte[] file)
    {
        byte[] result;

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(ms));
            PdfDocument sourcePdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(file)));                
            var pages = sourcePdf.GetNumberOfPages();                
            PageSize nUpPageSize = PageSize.A4;
            PdfPage targetPage = pdf.AddNewPage(nUpPageSize);
            PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(targetPage);                

            //if we remove ConcatMatrix we get nothing
            //otherwise it appears too small
            for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
            {
                PdfPage currentPage = sourcePdf.GetPage(i);
                Rectangle orig = targetPage.GetPageSize();
                var width = nUpPageSize.GetWidth() / orig.GetWidth() / 2f;
                var height = nUpPageSize.GetHeight() / orig.GetHeight() / 2f;
                AffineTransform transformationMatrix = AffineTransform.GetScaleInstance(
                width, height);
                canvas.ConcatMatrix(transformationMatrix);

                var height1 = orig.GetHeight();
                var width2 = orig.GetWidth() / 2;
                var height2 = orig.GetHeight() / 2;

                PdfFormXObject pageCopy = currentPage.CopyAsFormXObject(pdf);
                if (i == 1)
                    canvas.AddXObject(pageCopy, 0, height1);                    
                else
                    canvas.AddXObject(pageCopy,0, 1200);

            }                
            // close the documents
            pdf.Close();
            sourcePdf.Close();
            canvas.Release();
            result = ms.GetBuffer();
        }


        return result;
    }
```

Comment: The `AddXObject` calls here add their respective `pageCopy` way beyond the upper page border.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, I didnt want to scale it smaller so I used 0.99 to keep the original size, if I use 1 then it doesn't appear at all.

The y position of the second page is using a minus value.. if I used +400 then it disappeared off the page, 0 it overlay-ed with the first page contents, but minus it continued to shift down. :)

```
 //if we remove ConcatMatrix we get nothing
            //otherwise it appears to small
            //setting transformation to 1 shows nothing
            for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
            {
                PdfPage currentPage = sourcePdf.GetPage(i);
                Rectangle orig = targetPage.GetPageSize();
                var width = 0.99f;//= nUpPageSize.GetWidth() / orig.GetWidth() / 2f;
                var height = 0.99f;//nUpPageSize.GetHeight() / orig.GetHeight() / 2f;
                AffineTransform transformationMatrix = AffineTransform.GetScaleInstance(
                width, height);
                canvas.ConcatMatrix(transformationMatrix);

                var height1 = orig.GetHeight();
                var width2 = orig.GetWidth() / 2;
                var height2 = orig.GetHeight() / 2;

                PdfFormXObject pageCopy = currentPage.CopyAsFormXObject(pdf);
                if (i == 1)                                         
                    canvas.AddXObject(pageCopy, 0, 0); 
                else                      
                    canvas.AddXObject(pageCopy, 0, -400);

            }
```

Comment: *"The y position of the second page is using a minus value"* - well... obviously, after all you want the content of the second page under the content of the first one, so obviously negative after you added the first page at 0.

Comment: *"if I use 1 then it doesn't appear at all."* - that would very much surprise me. Can you share a sample source PDF for which that happens?